# Spring Injecting map with value-type being an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to inject this HashMap to my CentralCache bean, in which Cacheable is an interface. And inside the applicationContext.xml file I have:

```xml
    <bean id="externalSystemView" class="beans.ExternalSystemViewBean"> 
    </bean>

    <util:map id="cacheMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="caches.CacheableBean">
        <entry key="externalSystemView" value-ref="externalSystemView" />
    </util:map>

    <bean id="centralCache" class="caches.CentralCache">
        <property name="cacheableBeanMap" ref="cacheMap"/>
    </bean>
```

And here is my CacheableBean interface:

```java
    public interface CacheableBean extends Serializable{
        public void update();
    }
```

And my ExternalSystemViewBean which is the value of the map entry:

```java
    @ManagedBean(name="externalSystemView")
    public class ExternalSystemViewBean implements CacheableBean {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2314127844478571215L;

        ...

        @Override
        public void update() {
             ...
        }

    }
```

And finally my CentralCache:

```java
    public class CentralCache {
    private CacheManager cm;
    private HashMap<String, CacheableBean> cacheableBeanMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    private HashMap<String, CacheWrapper> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CentralCache.class);

    public CentralCache() {
        logger.info("creating CentralCache bean.");
        this.cm = CacheManager.create();
    }

    public HashMap<String, CacheableBean> getCacheableBeanMap() {
        return this.cacheableBeanMap;
    }

    public void setCacheableBeanMap(HashMap<String, CacheableBean> cacheableBeanMap) {
        logger.info("Starting to assign properties");
        for (Map.Entry<String, CacheableBean> entry : cacheableBeanMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = (String) entry.getKey();
            CacheableBean value = (CacheableBean) entry.getValue();
            CacheWrapper wrapper = new CacheWrapper(key, this.cm, value);
            this.cacheMap.put(key, wrapper);
        }
    }

    public CacheableBean getBean(String beanName) {
        return cacheMap.get(beanName).getBean();
    }
}
```

And it gives me the following error:

```java
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralCache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'cacheableBeanMap' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1427)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1090)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1900)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'cacheableBeanMap' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
        ... 26 more
```

However if I change the value-type to ExternalSystemViewBean itself (of course any relative things inside related classes). It will work. So Spring does not support interface as map's value type? Or it does not support any super types inside of map's value type?